# Calculate sum of mapped values for each unique value in a flat array

Tags: php, arrays, sum, mapping, grouping

I have a loop where I push values into two arrays simultaneously, so I get two arrays like this:

```
$array1 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3];
$array2 = [2, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5];
```

How can I get the sum for each unique number of `$array1`, meaning `1,2,3`, for the corresponding keys of that number from `$array2`.

Example; for the value `1` of the `$array1` we got the keys `0, 1, 2`. Now I want to sum up the values from `$array2` which have those keys, resulting in `2 + 4 + 5 = 11`.

Would I write a loop to get all the indexes that have `1` in `$array1` and then get all the values from `$array2` with those indexes and so on?

Desired output:

```
[1 => 11, 2 => 3, 3 => 5]
```

Comment: Last paragraph:  yes, that is what you can do. Try to do it and if you get stuck post the code and we will help you to finish it.

Comment: is it possible that `$array1` would have values in random order in your case, like `[ 1 , 1 , 1 , 3 , 2 , 3, 2 ]` ?

Comment: lets just assume that they will be in order.

Comment: @gavgrif Your answer is a good proposal, if OP pushes values into both arrays simultaneously, then he can add those numbers together right away.

Comment: yes, I am pushing them in at the same time, what is the proposal? it appears the answer was deleted.

Comment: @scott.schaffer Here: https://3v4l.org/DXi0v I wrote it in pseudo code what he wrote and declared what the proposal is with `//new code`. The result/output would then be in `$sum` (`print_r($sum);`).

Comment: one thing that is tripping me up with this explanation, is that I am pushing them in at the same time for the 2 arrays, per 1 index at a time, from a 'foreach' loop. so im trying to compare them after the array is filled up. does this still work for this situation?

Comment: @scott.schaffer I'm not sure if I get you, but yes just initialize a sum array before the loop, then check if you have a key with the value of the first array in sum and if not initialize it with the value 0, then you can add the corresponding value to it.

Comment: @scott.schaffer gavgrif undeleted his answer now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36240622/3933332 I would recommend you to take a look at his answer, since it is probably the best possible answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_map` passing to function the two arrays and using a reference to an empty array with each total:

```
$total = array_fill_keys( array_unique($array1), 0 );

array_map
(
    function( $a, $b ) use( &$total )
    {
        $total[$a] += $b;
    },
    $array1,
    $array2
);

print_r( $total );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 5
)
```

<kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/542646)**</kbd>

`array_map` accepts more than one array, and pass its each item synchronized, so you can sum each `$array2` value to `$total` element with same key as `$array1` value.

Note that we init `$total` with `array_fill_keys` only to avoid notices on creating new `$total` elements.

Comment: Good answer with a good explanation! Also like that `array_fill_keys()` instead of checking in the callback every time if that particular element is already initialized with 0. But I don't get why you used `@`? I mean you already initialized the array and if the 2 arrays are of unequal amounts then it will just go: `NULL -> 0`.

Comment: @Rizier123 I forgot to delete it. It was my first solution, before use `array_fill_keys()`. Good catch, as usual! Thank you.

Comment: @scott.schaffer You are welcome. The Rizier123 answer is more brilliant.

Comment: @fusion3k Well even though my code is slightly faster than yours and unnoticeable as long as you don't do these operations thousands of times. I think since your solution uses less code it is a bit easier to read/understand. But the real answer which should be accepted is sadly deleted and I'm trying to figure out why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240418/sum-array-values-based-on-key-intersection#comment60112488_36240418 to get it undeleted

Answer (score 2):

If you're already pushing values into `$array1` and at the same time the same for `$array2`, why not simply create a third array and push values of the second array into the sum of the corresponding element, with the key from the first array?!

Therefore you don't have to call any additional functions that do this and you can do it right in the loop itself.

Pseudo code:

```
<?php

    $sum = [];

    loop {

        $arrayOne[] = $valueOne;
        $arrayTwo[] = $valueTwo;


        if(!isset($sum[$valueOne]))
            $sum[$valueOne] = 0;
        $sum[$valueOne] += $valueTwo;

    }

    print_r($sum);

?>
```

So with this you end up with an array having a pattern like this:

```
Array (
    [unique value from array one] => sum
)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Explanation

First we get all unique values from `$array1` just by flipping it with [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php). Since you can't have duplicate keys, we end up with all unique values as keys in `$uniqueValues`. We also initialize `$sum` with an empty array, where we will put the sum for each value into it.

Now we loop through all our unique values and get all keys from `$array1`, which have that particular value with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

Then we get all values from the second array with those keys which we do with [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php). Note, that since we do the intersection by key we have to flip our keys array so that we have the keys as keys of the array.

After that we have all values from `$array2` in an array, which corresponds to the value of the first array from the current iteration. And we can just sum it together with [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and save it in `$sum`.

#### Code

```
<?php

    $array1 = [ 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 ];
    $array2 = [ 2 , 4 , 5 , 2 , 1 , 5 ];

    $sum = [];
    $uniqueValues = array_flip($array1);

    foreach($uniqueValues as $v => $notNeeded){
        $keys = array_keys($array1, $v);
        $sum[$v] = array_sum(array_intersect_key($array2, array_flip($keys)));
    }

    print_r($sum);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 5
)
```

Comment: thank you, I will try this solution out as well.. so many great ways presented here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use functional approach with [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
<?php

$array1 = [ 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 ];
$array2 = [ 2 , 4 , 5 , 2 , 1 , 5 ];

$newArray = array_reduce($array1, function($carry, $item) use($array2) {
    $item2 = $array2[$carry['index']];
    $carry[$item] = empty($carry[$item]) ? $item2 : $carry[$item] + $item2;
    $carry['index'] = $carry['index'] + 1;
    return $carry;
}, ['index' => 0]);

unset($newArray['index']);
var_dump($newArray);
```

Output will be:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  int(11)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(5)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. if the answer above doesn't work out, I will try yours as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for ordered sequence (such as `1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3`) using `array_count_values`, `array_walk` and `array_sum` functions:

```
$array1 = [ 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 ];
$array2 = [ 2 , 4 , 5 , 2 , 1 , 5 ];

$counts = array_count_values($array1);
$offset = 0;
$sums = [];

array_walk($counts, function($v, $k) use($counts, &$sums, $array2, &$offset){
    $offset += isset($counts[$k-1])? $counts[$k-1] : 0;
    $sums[$k] = array_sum(array_slice($array2, $offset, $v));
});

print_r($sums);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 5
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Answer (score 0):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59856172/2943403), loop over the mapping array, then group and sum as repeated identifying values are encountered.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nUo0q))

```
$array1 = [1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3];
$array2 = [2 , 4 , 5 , 2 , 1 , 5];

$result = [];
foreach ($array1 as $index => $id) {
    $result[$id] = ($result[$id] ?? 0) + $array2[$index];
}
var_export($result);
```