# Group and sum mapped values from two flat arrays of equal length

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I have two arrays. They are always the same length. If the first array element value is the same then sum of the second array element value.

**Example**

```
$array1 = array(1,2,2,3);
$array2 = array(10,20,30,50);

// I can get the sum of array1 and array2 output.
$array_sum1 = array(10,50,50);


$array3 = array(4,4,4,6);
$array4 = array(10,20,30,50);

// I can get the sum of array3 and array4 output.
$array_sum2 = array(60,50);
```

How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: I wasn't able to understand what you trying to do. Can you please try to elaborate?

Comment: Use array_sum. more details here [https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_sum.asp]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array_sum with array_map like below,

```
$array1     = [1, 2, 2, 3];
$array2     = [10, 20, 30, 50];
$array_sum1 = [];
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $array_sum1[$value][] = $array2[$key];
}
$array_sum1 = array_map("array_sum", $array_sum1);
print_r($array_sum1);
$array3     = [4, 4, 4, 6];
$array4     = [10, 20, 30, 50];
$array_sum2 = [];
foreach ($array3 as $key => $value) {
    $array_sum2[$value][] = $array4[$key];
}
$array_sum2 = array_map("array_sum", $array_sum2);
print_r($array_sum2);die;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/5sXjt)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 50
    [3] => 50
)
Array
(
    [4] => 60
    [6] => 50
)
```

Comment: Your welcome. If you want to reset indexes of array use [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). [Demo](https://3v4l.org/YCFEg)

Answer (score 1):

It is indirect to perform two iterations of your data to group & sum.

Use the "id" values as keys in your output array.  If a given "id" is encountered for the first time, then save the "val" value to the "id"; after the first encounter, add the "val" to the "id".

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/14Z4O))

```
$ids = [1, 2, 2, 3];
$vals = [10, 20, 30, 50];
  
$result = [];
foreach ($ids as $index => $id) {
    $result[$id] = ($result[$id] ?? 0) + $vals[$index];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 10,
  2 => 50,
  3 => 50,
)
```